# Remove http://ip-address and Point to http://domain.com

Tags: apache, dns, bitnami, google-cloud-launcher

I just set up my website using Google Cloud, Bitnami, and Wordpress.

It goes to http://000.000.000.000 <-- Ip Address

Instead of http://domain.com <-- Real site.

How do I change the DNS setting to only point to http://domain.com?

Or do I need to change something in Apache in Bitnami?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access WordPress using your domain name instead of using the IP of the server, you can edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php file and set the WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME variables:

You will need to replace these lines:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');    
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

with these ones:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://yourdomain.com');
```

You will find more information about this in our documentation system:

https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/wordpress/#how-to-change-the-wordpress-domain-name

I hope this helps.

Jota Martos